# Call and get specific sheet information with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am referring the Google spreadsheet, which has multiple sheets, as data source for my dashboard.

How can I refer particular sheet from spreadsheet while defining the data source for filter and charts.

Code Snippets

---

```
// This spreadsheet has more than one sheet

var datasource= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Vw1AYwLgPNbWX93kYOzQkMbYufmDPjvOT1q2P-GQyzQ');

var data =datasource.getDataRange();

// Here I would like to mention sheet2 of spreadsheet as data source from the spreadsheet
var companyFilter=Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).setDataTable(**data**).build();
```

I cannot use two different data source variable  for each sheet as I am referring it further in dashboard which includes charts based on data from two different sheet.

```
// table chart is based on data in sheet2 and rest other charts is based on sheet1 data.
var dashboard1 = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(**data**)
.bind([companyFilter],[tableChart,barChart,investedpieChart,currentpieChart])
.build();
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can not use two data source variable? Don't you want to use two different `var datasource` or two different `var data`?

Comment: @Mörre

How do I mention two data sources in the .setDataTable(datasource) method which I am using in dashboard panel.

note: data source of tableChart,barChart is sheet 1 and for chart investedpieChart,currentpieChart data source  is sheet2









var dashboard1 = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
.bind([companyFilter],[tableChart,barChart,investedpieChart,currentpieChart])
.build();

Answer (score 0):

You can get a sheet by name:

[Google Documentation - getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

You can get a reference to two sheets at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.


How do I mention two data sources in the .setDataTable(datasource) method which I am using in dashboard panel.                           


                                                                 note: data source of tableChart,barChart is sheet 1 and for chart investedpieChart,currentpieChart data source is sheet2. 

Code Snippet                                                            var dashboard1 = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data) .bind([companyFilter],[tableChart,barChart,investedpieChart,currentpieChart]) .build();